# How to delete the border of the edge for character recognition in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-recognition

i want to do a segmentation of the character from vehicle plate an do recognition with template matching.
But after i do some basic step in image processing, the output image has a border so the border is detected as a another character.
How to fix it??

Here is my code :

```
% Resizing the image keeping aspect ratio same.
citra=imresize(citra,[400 NaN]);

% Converting the RGB (color) image to gray (intensity).
citra_bw=rgb2gray(citra);

citra_bw= imclearborder(citra_bw);
imshow(citra_bw);

% Median filtering to remove noise.
citra_filt=medfilt2(citra_bw,[5 5]); 
se=strel('disk',3);

% Dilating the gray image with the structural element.
citra_dilasi=imdilate(citra_filt,se); 

% Eroding the gray image with structural element.
citra_eroding=imerode(citra_filt,se);

% Morphological Gradient for edges enhancement.
citra_edge_enhacement=imsubtract(citra_dilasi,citra_eroding); 

imshow(citra_edge_enhacement);

% Converting the class to double.
citra_edge_enhacement_double=mat2gray(double(citra_edge_enhacement)); 

% Convolution of the double image f
citra_double_konv=conv2(citra_edge_enhacement_double,[1 1;1 1]); 

% Intensity scaling between the range 0 to 1.
citra_intens=imadjust(citra_double_konv,[0.5 0.7],[0 1],0.1); 

% Conversion of the class from double to binary.
% Eliminating the possible horizontal lines 
% from the output image of regiongrow
% that could be edges of license plate.
citra_logic=logical(citra_intens);  


citra_line_delete=imsubtract(citra_logic,(imerode(citra_logic,...
                                                  strel('line',50,0))));

% Filling all the regions of the image.
citra_fill=imfill(citra_line_delete,'holes');

% Thinning the image to ensure character isolation.         
citra_thinning_eroding=imerode((bwmorph(citra_fill,'thin',1)),...
                               (strel('line',3,90)));

%Selecting all the regions that are of pixel area more than 100.
citra_final=bwareaopen(citra_thinning_eroding,125);
imshow(citra_final);
```

here is the original image:

[image: original image]
<sub>(source: [plateshack.com](http://www.plateshack.com/y2k/Indonesia/bandung,west_java.jpg))</sub>

and here is the processed image with the border in the character

[image: processed image with the border in the character]

Comment: I don't understand, which border r u referring to. The one around D or G, or something else?

Comment: To put it simply. Your morphological statements 'imerode' and 'imdialate' seem to be doing more harm than good. I would suggest that you re-evaluate the need for these functions and perhaps try using a tiled threshold method like sauvola or local adaptive threshold. Perform corrections after this step if necessary and not before.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure if your algorithm is really optimized. It seems to be elaborate, but not fitting to your problem.

I would simply try a binarization (not using the "logical" command) and then play around with imerode and bwareaopen to get rid of the small stuff around the characters. This should be simpler than your code ...